# as.date converting dates to the wrong year

Tags: r, as.date

I am trying to convert t in this dataframe (mbt2) to date. Dates from 1957-2020.

```
        t     temp
1    1/01/1957 36.1
2    2/01/1957 31.1
3    3/01/1957 31.7
4    4/01/1957 32.2
5    5/01/1957 32.2
6    6/01/1957 34.0
```

I have used the following

`mbt2$t <- as.Date(mbt2$t , format = "%d/%m/%y")`

However it is converting every year to 2019 except 2020. 
I've looked through other questions and haven't found anything that helps yet.
Any ideas how to fix this?
Thank you :)

Comment: Uppercase "Y", not lowercase: `mbt2$t <- as.Date(mbt2$t , format = "%d/%m/%Y")`.

Comment: Thank you, so simple :). Do I need to correct for leap years using this code?

Comment: I don't understand. Correct what for leap years?

Comment: It's okay it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this format instead:
`mbt2$t <- as.Date(mbt2$t , format = "%d/%m/%Y")`

`%y` is 2-digit year, while `%Y` is 4-digit year. Your version reads just first 2 digits from `1957` and that's why it returns `2019`.